# Show that a function $N:\mathcal Y \rightarrow \mathbb R _+$ defined by $N(y)= \left\lvert \int_a^b y(x) dx \right\rvert$ doesn't define a norm...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $\mathcal Y=C([a,b])$. Show that the function $N:\mathcal Y \rightarrow \mathbb R _+$ defined by
>   $$N(y)= \left\lvert \int_a^b y(x) dx \right\rvert$$
>   does not define a norm on $\mathcal Y$.

I was able to find a similar question which was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453066/how-do-i-prove-that-the-following-integral-is-a-norm), where it is clearly shown how to prove that

$$\|f(x)\|:= \int_a^b \vert y(x) \vert dx$$

*is* a norm on $C([a,b])$.

I am basically confused as to how my question differs from the question that can be found at the aforementioned link. Obviously, the placement of the absolute value signs must have a critical impact on either **Positive Definiteness**, the **Triangle Inequality**, or **Homogeneity**, but I can't see how that will play out. It seems to me like the two functions are identical.

My only guess here is that the mapping of the function $N:\mathcal Y \rightarrow \mathbb R _+$ might have an important impact, but I'm not quite sure how...

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say, $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and $y(x)=x$, then $y$ is not the zero function but $N(y)=\left|\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}xdx\right|=0$.

Triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
N(y+z)&=\left|\int_{a}^{b}(y+z)(x)dx\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{a}^{b}y(x)dx+\int_{a}^{b}z(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq\left|\int_{a}^{b}y(x)dx\right|+\left|\int_{a}^{b}z(x)dx\right|\\
&=N(y)+N(z).
\end{align*}

Comment: For general $[a,b]$, consider the positive slope straight line that passing by the midpoint $((a+b)/2,0)$ with equal areas on left-right sided triangle, then the integral is still zero.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and I see why your counter-example wouldn't hamper the other function.

Comment: Would the Triangle Inequality and Homogeneity still hold?

Comment: Yes, as I can see, it will.

Comment: If you would be able to show how the Triangle Inequality holds in particular, that would be a huge help. If not, no worries. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: Highly appreciated!